Get Twitter tweets using snscrape
Can somebody please help me on this.I copied and pasted the code word to word from a YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtIMnmbnOFo&t=1s and yet there is still an Attribute Error occurring can somebody point out the issue:
This is the code
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sns
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# Define your custom query
query = "python"

for tweet in sns.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items():
    print(vars(tweet))
    break

Output should return tweets about Python on Twitter
OUTPUT ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ambai\PycharmProjects\Twitter\tweets.py", line 1, in <module>
    import snscrape.modules.twitter as sns
  File "C:\Users\ambai\PycharmProjects\Twitter\.venv\Lib\site-packages\snscrape\modules\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    _import_modules()
  File "C:\Users\ambai\PycharmProjects\Twitter\.venv\Lib\site-packages\snscrape\modules\__init__.py", line 13, in _import_modules
    module = importer.find_module(moduleName).load_module(moduleName)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'FileFinder' object has no attribute 'find_module'


maybe you can try another python version like 3.9 or 3.10 since some dependency for snscrape is no longer available in the latest version

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
